# Launch javascript [ window:print() ] after page with additional javascript loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, google-analytics

I have a page that is loading around 10 google analytics charts. I would like to launch a print dialog box once this page fully loads -- all charts / javascript loaded. Unfortunately, at the moment the print dialog box opens after the DOM is loaded; however, during this time javascript is still working on loading all the google charts for about another 2-3 seconds, so when the print dialog box appears, the areas where the chart should be displayed are coming up blank.

My code at the moment is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.onload = function() { 
    window.print(); 
  }
</script>
```

Is there a way of achieving my desired result so that the print dialogue box appears only after the entire page (including all other javascript) loads?

I sincerely appreciate any suggestions you may have, and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If the function getting your chart has a callback function (I hope so, this is the base for nonimmediate functions) and if the number of charts you load is a constant you can add a variable `var chartsLoaded = 0`, when a chart is loaded add this in the callback function:

```
chartsLoaded++;
if (chartsLoaded == myConstantNumberOfCharts) 
    window.print();
```

It seems really simple with the information you have given, don't hesitate to give more details if the problem is more complex.